# Firebase. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, classnotfoundexception

I try to implement push notification through the new Firebase GCM implementation. 
It's quite simple:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.MyMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".services.MyInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But these services are not necessary too.
Of course I inserted gradle plugin for code generation of GCM classes at the end of build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
and also have this in project gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

When I launch app and try to send a notification from firebase to the application, it's crashes with a strange reflection error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
```

I don't know even how to debug this error.

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue @eugene-verichev?

Comment: yes, now I posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the crash was not from firebase, it was from library that rely on the old implementation of firebase. 
In my case that was 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricapushlib:$version'.
And with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$project.ext.google_play_services_version' it will cause crash.
I decided not to use new libraries of firebase yet and implemented it with gcm library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Eugene. You're completely right. I found it as well. I was affected by a library called Intercom. However I was lucky and Intercom had the FCM version available as well!

Comment: Thank you, I had the same Intercom problem when taking over a legacy project.

I changed
```
implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:5.+'
```
to
```
implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:5.+'
implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:5.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears when GCM is upgraded to Firebase.

Delete `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. I just removed react-native-push-notification from my dependencies and now it solve my problem.